# Двойное управление у существительного

Tags: подчинительная-связь

Будьте добры, имеет ли существительное "владение" свойство двойного управления? В опыте устного общения и даже в официальных документах оно мне встречалось: "... владение лицом, обратившимся..., ключом ЭП..." - т.е. владение кем-л. (КТО владеет) чем-л. (ЧЕМ он владеет).
Данная конструкция кажется неудобочитаемой. К тому же, соответствующий глагол "владеть", если не ошибаюсь, лишён двойного управления.
Разъясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фраза неудобочитаемая, хотя без полного контекста сказать сложно.
Это, пожалуй все, с чем могу согласиться. Без контекста фразу сложно классифицировать даже как стилистическую ошибку.

Что касается грамматики, то она не нарушена, что такое двойное управление в данном случае и почему оно запрещено, судить не берусь.
действительно, глагол "владеть", как правило, выступает в роли  одновалентного (пациенс - владеть чем), но у нас-то существительное "владение", это меняет дело. Здесь возможно и появление агенса (кто владеет).

Для сравнения. Вот похожий глагол "управлять". У*правлять транспортным средством*. Другого не дано. Но конструкция типа *"управления автомобилем лицом, не достигшим совершеннолетия...*" выглядит вполне нормальной.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ.

Comment: В тех учебниках, по которым я учился, не было терминов "агенс" и "пациенс".

Comment: Проблема в том, что оба слова, зависимых от существительного, стоят в одном падеже, причём их можно произвольно переставлять. Воображаю, как ломают голову иностранцы над подобными предложениями.

Comment: @БорисСелютин *не было терминов "агенс" и "пациенс"* - Это термины общей лингвистики. В первом приближении они означают "субъект" и "объект" действия соответвенно.